# Cannot connect to bastion host in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, host, bastion

I am following the guide in https://aws-quickstart.s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-bitnami-wordpress/doc/wordpress-high-availability-by-bitnami-on-the-aws-cloud.pdf to create a WordPress High Availability on AWS.

The creation succeeds. And I can visit the WordPress site and the admin panel. However, when I follow the instructions in section "Option 2. Connect to the cluster through SSH", I find I cannot connect to the Bastion host instance. I always get the error "Connection timed out".

Since I am using SecureCRT, not ssh or PuTTY, so I doubt that there may be some misconfiguration in SecureCRT or it does not work for Amazon EC2 instances. So I try to create a test EC2 instance, and then find I can connect to it with SecureCRT successfully, with the key pair same as that for the Bastion host.

So what I have done wrong? Or what log can I check to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*SSH Timeout* usually points to a *Firewall* or *Security Group* issue. One way or another your SecureCRT is blocked from accessing the Bastion host on the network level. Make sure that the Security Group associated with the instance has a rule that allows SSH from your external IP address.

Comment: Thank you. I find a security group called "Enables SSH Access to Bastion Hosts", then add a rule to allow all IPs, then that works.